# How to limit query results?

Tags: android, neo4j, cypher

Hi guys i'm developing an app using clojure and neo4j,i got an issue in limiting query results eg:suppose i have 20 nodes as result,i need to display 5 nodes per request again 5 nodes per request so on i don't want to load all 20 results at time so that memory becomes high.Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

In the cypher query you can use the [`LIMIT` clause](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-return.html).

It can be used in various places in the query, but in particular in the `RETURN` section. See the [Neo4J Cypher cheatsheet](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-refcard/) ref.

As @logisima noted you will need also the [`SKIP` clause](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-skip.html) to do your pagination.

An example query is the following:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
WHERE < your conditions here >
RETURN DISTINCT a,b LIMIT 50 SKIP 50;
```

It will return 50 "records" (`LIMIT 50`) starting from the 51st (`SKIP 50`).

Comment: you also need the SKIP clause to make your pagination. Example to have page 2 with a 5 row per pages :
MATCH (n)
RETURN n SKIP 5 LIMIT 5